# R: How to replace all instances of a text phrase in a table

Tags: r

I have a table like the following:

```
A, B, 
"Yes", 1
"Yes", 2
"No", 3
```

Is there any easy way to substitute all the cells with "Yes" for "Hello" instead so I get:

```
A, B, 
"Hello", 1
"Hello", 2
"No", 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use indexing (assuming the column 'A' is `character` class

```
df$A[df$A == 'Yes'] <- 'Hello'
```

---

Or with `ifelse`

```
df$A <- with(df, ifelse(A == 'Yes', 'Hello', A))
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what is df$a?

Edit: Nevermind, df is the name of the table and $A means the column A

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Alex I assume that the the data showed is a data.frame and here the object name is 'df' and the 'A' is the column name.  We extract the columns as vector with `$` or `[[` or [`